# js code in one html section not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

when you reduce the browser window there will be a different iphone lay out...

When I put the js into one html sections its not working....
but if i put js in fiddle js section its working properly....
can you tell the reason....
the problem is my li tags are not getting values from js...
can you tell whats the reason....
providing my code below....

working code....

http://jsfiddle.net/YZYp5/7/

not working code....

http://jsfiddle.net/YZYp5/3/

```
<li style="display: table-cell; width: 417px; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid red; left: -417px; -webkit-transition: 300ms; -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);" data-index="1">
```

the problem is with this function

```
function translate(index, dist, speed) {

    var slide = slides[index];
    var style = slide && slide.style;

    if (!style) return;

    style.webkitTransitionDuration = 
    style.MozTransitionDuration = 
    style.msTransitionDuration = 
    style.OTransitionDuration = 
    style.transitionDuration = speed + 'ms';

    style.webkitTransform = 'translate(' + dist + 'px,0)' + 'translateZ(0)';
    style.msTransform = 
    style.MozTransform = 
    style.OTransform = 'translateX(' + dist + 'px)';

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```
var style = slide && slide.style;
```

That will make `style` a boolean value, not an object. You're probably looking for something like this:

```
var style = slide && slide.style ? slide.style : {};
```

Comment: i put your code in this fiddle but its not working.....  function translate(index, dist, speed) {

        var slide = slides[index];
       var style = slide && slide.style ? slide.style : {};

        if (!style) return;

        style.webkitTransitionDuration = style.MozTransitionDuration = style.msTransitionDuration = style.OTransitionDuration = style.transitionDuration = speed + 'ms';

        style.webkitTransform = 'translate(' + dist + 'px,0)' + 'translateZ(0)';
        style.msTransform = style.MozTransform = style.OTransform = 'translateX(' + dist + 'px)';

    }

Comment: i am getting one error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined http://jsfiddle.net/YZYp5/9/embedded/result/

Comment: That error comes from somewhere else, there's nothing in the translate function trying to set a className. Sorry, but your jsfiddle has too much code, you should try to cut it down to the minimum size required to reproduce the particular issue you're asking about.

Comment: <li style="display: table-cell; width: 417px; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid red; left: -417px; -webkit-transition: 300ms; -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);" data-index="1">  this li is not getting js values....when i give manually the values in firebug its working...convert the translate into -417px